# Norm of matrix and linear mapping with Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

On page **175** of Edward's *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables*, there is the following theorem:

**Theorem 2.3** Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be the matrix of the linear mapping $L:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$, that is, $Lx = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}.$ Then $$||L|| = ||A||.$$

Now, there is a rather long proof for this theorem in the book. I was wondering if I could prove it by saying that the result follows immediately from *Riesz Representation Theorem*. If not, how can I prove this theorem by using it? I have the intuition that it is easier through that path.

*Note: The proof written in the book uses propositions on the sup norm and a lot of inequalities.*

Comment: If you'd like for someone to answer your question, including the definitions of both $\|L\|$ and $\|A\|$ may be worthwhile. With some of possible definitions, this equality is a tautology.